# How to integrate Emoji into link_to

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, emoji, link-to

I want to use an Emoji, e.g. Trash-Emoji (HTML Entity: & #x1f5d1;) inside link_to, like:

```
<%= link_to "&#x1f5d1;", tape_path(tape.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure to delete?' }, class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm btn-warning' %>
```

But no Trash-Emoji itself is showing.
I also tried "& #x1f5d1;", #{& #x1f5d1;}, & #x1f5d1; but syntac errors were shown.

I want to try to write without using any additional GEM at first.
Does someone know how should be written?

Comment: `<%= link_to "" ...%>` or `<%= link_to "\u{1f5d1}" ...%>` should work.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan! both are working!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`html_safe` and `raw` are not very flexible approaches when you want to make a really customized link

It is more elegant to use `block` where you can do A LOT:

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
  Homepage
  <div class="fa fa-flag"></div>
  &#x1f5d1;
  <%= User.count %>
<% end %>
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Your case:

```
<%= link_to root_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure to delete?' }, class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm btn-warning' do %>
  &#x1f5d1;
<% end %>
```

Comment: WOW! It's totally new method for me and it's working well! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem to use "link_to raw" now!

```
<%= link_to raw("&#x1f5d1;").html_safe, tape_path(tape.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure to delete?' }, class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm btn-warning' %>
```

Comment: `raw` and `html_safe` are equivalent here, you only need one.